# How to change the default Podman Machine? Ex.: From `podman-machine-default` to `myvm`

Tags: podman

I want to keep track of different machines to be able to configure different proxys for each machine.

*How can I set a new machine as Podman's default machine?*

In the documentation there is `podman machine init myvm` to create a new machine but couldn't find any refence on how to access it.

I searched a lot to try to find this already, but no tutorial mention this, as it's kind of a uncommon use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of effort and investigation, found this:

```
podman system connection default <name>
```

This will set the default machine to the desired name.

I also recommend checking the list before selecting the machine, as there are rootful and rootless options:

```
podman system connection list
```

Result:

```
Name                         URI                                                          Identity                                      Default
podman-machine-default       ssh://user@127.0.0.1:57864/run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock  <User>\.ssh\podman-machine-default            false
podman-machine-default-root  ssh://root@127.0.0.1:57864/run/podman/podman.sock            <User>\.ssh\podman-machine-default            false
```

If you don't want to change the default machine, you can also use the `-c` flag before the command to specify another machine:

```
podman -c myvm images
```